# Is it possible to add a Facebook 'Like' button to my site without registering as a developer?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I want to simply add the Facebook button that shows the counter for the number of likes this site has received, but it seems that Facebook doesn't want me to.

This is the site I find when I search for it:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

But then I try to generate the code, I am referenced this FAQ link:

https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=17580

which says that I need a credit card to verify my developer account.

So not only do I have to register as a developer, I have to give Facebook my credit card?

WTF!

I get it is for Anti-spam purposes, but really man....a credit card? Just to put a damn FB link on my page - something that they should actually pay me to do, because it increaes their SEO rank (which I know they don't need).

Google's +1 button is very easy to integrate: http://www.google.com/intl/en/webmasters/+1/button/index.html

Twitter's Tweet button: http://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton

Just as easy.

Can someone let me know if I am seeing the wrong resources for FB and there is an easier way, or is FB just off their rockers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember setting this up at my old job a while back, and I know we had a developer account.

On the site, I see

```
To use this plug-in, your site must have an application ID. You can get 
an application ID by registering your site. Replace APP_ID in the above 
script with your application ID.
```

Unfortunately, it looks like you'll have to set up a developer's account :\

Comment: Ok Thanks. That's what I figured. Damn FB! Well, that's one less site with one, for sure.